# Wordpress thumbnail grid with expanding preview

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am using this component

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/

DEMO
http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/

implemented in wordpress for my portfolio.

looking at the html code

```
<li>
    <a href="http://cargocollective.com/jaimemartinez/" data-largesrc="images/1.jpg" data-title="Azuki bean" data-description="Swiss chard pumpkin bunya nuts maize plantain aubergine napa cabbage soko coriander sweet pepper water spinach winter purslane shallot tigernut lentil beetroot.">
        <img src="images/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="img01"/>
    </a>
</li>
```

link href allow me to run-down the project to read the specifications of the project

the problem is this:
In the href in wordpress what should I put in?

Answer (score 0):

The Previous answer that was deleted was correct. I got this to work problem was that I was incorrectly loading the Modernizr script. 
To see an example of my working grid in wordpress I uploaded it here. http://webshowcase.tk/wp1/.

In order to use this with wordpress you tags need to be converted to wordpress tags and all the info in the data tags need to be wordpress tags also. In the case of 
<a href = .... > </a>it would look like this.

```
<a href= "<?php the_permalink() ?>" data-largesrc="<?php echo $url; ?>" data-title="<?php the_title(); ?>" data-description="<?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>"
```

http://cargocollective.com/jaimemartinez/" is the same as < ?php the_permalink() ?>
data-title="Azuki bean" would be data-title="<?php the_title(); ?>"
data-description="Swis... etc" would be data-description="<?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>"

data-largsrc is the location of your image. in my case <?php echo $url; ?> I assigned $url to contain the location of the posts featured post custom thumbnail size image and to a default image at the same size if the post has no image which is show in my previous answer.